# appendChild returning Cannot read property 'containerDiv' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add a div element to my top level div container, but for some reason I get an error.

Here's my code. It's a button, that once you click, is supposed to add a box on the screen.

To avoid the jQuery bug with `this.`, I defined a variable on top of my class, called `self`

```
var self = this;
```

So this fixes the jQuery bug.

```
$(this.button).click(function() {
        self.newContainer = new divGenerator();

        self.containerDiv.parentNode.appendChild(self.newContainer.divContainer);

    });
```

What's really weird is that when I print out

```
console.log("self.newContainer: "+self.newContainer.containerDiv);
```

I get "`self.newContainer: [object HTMLDivElement]`" as the result. And an HTMLDivElement is exactly what I need, right? It's a node, and appendChild() needs a node element. So everythign seems right. But it's not. Why?

Comment: Who is the `this.button` origin?

Comment: `this.button = document.createElement("button");`

Comment: Could you post the `divGenerator()` code?

Comment: @CaioTarifa The divGenerator() is working perfectly if I add it to the screen manually - or in other words, not with a button click.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the error here... Consider post your code on http://www.jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you just use jQuery or vanilla JS? Why mix both?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me (and I may be reading this wrong, you'd have to post the internals of divGenerator for me to be certain) that your problem is simply a naming error... a typo if you will. In the following line:

```
self.containerDiv.parentNode.appendChild(self.newContainer.divContainer);
```

I notice that you are calling `divContainer` rather than `containerDiv` on `self.newContainer`. Unless you also have a property defined as `divContainer`, I'm guessing you just need to change the name of your property call to be `containerDiv`, as is the case in the rest of your code.

---

**Sidebar:** I noticed that you mention

> To avoid the jQuery bug with `this`, I defined a variable on top of my class, called `self`

To the best of my knowledge, there is no such "error" in jQuery. Rather, you are experiencing confusion regarding the usage of `this`, which is as a keyword referencing the current function context (i.e. the object within which you are currently operating).

Your solution is, in fact, a common idiom within JavaScript, allowing you to refer to an enclosing context by means of a variable assigned to `this` in the outer scope. I recommend reading [this article](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) to clarify your understanding of the `this` construct and how it can and should be used.